# Not able to access Windows Push Notifications Live Services website?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, push-notification, live

Am working on windows push notifications using free Live Services website. But from past 10 days Am not able to access the site and it showing that "This site was temporary and no longer in use".I want to know is the site for free users working? or anyone facing the same problem and Is there any free sites like Live services for Windows 8 Push Notifications?please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, that site is no longer in operation. In order to work with push notifications, you must now have a Windows Store developer account. You'll then be able to register your application and get the necessary SID and client secret to implement push notifications.

Comment: Jim O'Neil,Windows store developer account is a paid or free account?

Comment: they are paid accounts - [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694064.aspx#account_countries) for the pricing by country. There are programs under which you may have a free account as well, such as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com), [BizSpark](http://bizspark.com), and [DreamSpark](http://dreamspark.com), assuming you are eligible for those programs.